# Create Sequence Permission for Postgres

Tags: postgresql, permissions, sequence, authorization, acl

When my postgres function is tries to create a new sequence, it returns a `permission denied` error. It looks like the only way to make it work is to give `Create permission` on schema using the below statement.

```
GRANT CREATE ON SCHEMA public to "myuser"
```

But, this will allow the user to create any other type of object as well, including tables. How can we control this? I want my user to be able to create a sequence, but not tables.

Note: Create is not a valid grant on Sequences.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this using permissions. The only option would be to create an [event trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/event-triggers.html) that throws an exception if an undesirable object is created.

Answer (score 0):

From [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/308619/241191), an example of how to do this with an [event trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/event-triggers.html) is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_ddl_event_user()
RETURNS event_trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT current_user) = 'USER_TO_BLOCK' AND tg_tag NOT = 'CREATE SEQUENCE' THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'USER_TO_BLOCK tried to access a forbidden resource, the action was %', tg_tag;
    END IF;
END;
$$;

CREATE EVENT TRIGGER track_ddl_event
    ON ddl_command_start
    EXECUTE FUNCTION check_ddl_event_user();
```

Note that the trigger used is `ddl_command_start` which fires on a lot of events. The full list can be found [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/event-trigger-matrix.html)

Answer (score 0):

Make the  fuction have `security definer` then the actions taken by the fuction will be applied with the permissions of the creator of the function.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html